# mail file attachment limit

Tags: php, email, server, email-attachments

I have a php file which send mail with attachment.

Here is the code :

```
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$path = 'uploads';
$file = $path . "/" . $filename;

$mailto = 'mail@mail.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$message = 'My message';

$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (RFC)
$eol = "\r\n";

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: name <test@test.com>" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

// message
$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
$body .= $message . $eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

//SEND Mail
if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    print_r( error_get_last() );
}
```

When I upload a file < 8Mb it works perfectly, however when the file size is superior to 8Mb, the mail is not sent. I get the error `"mail send ... ERROR!"`

I looked into my phpinfo :

```
memory_limit    512M
upload_max_filesize 128M
post_max_size   64M
max_execution_time  300
```

Everything seems to be good...

the website is hosted by OVH, I tried it on a local server and got the same problem...

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: looks good to me. You sure there isn't a restriction in the form? That, or the host has it locked to that on their end.

Comment: So to be clear, _“the mail is not sent”_ explicitly means that mail() returned false, and therefor you get the error message from your else branch shown, yes?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't have a form, I only execute the script

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I edited my post

Comment: I don't see how you can send files without a form and a valid enctype or other means to handle files. Edit: Then again, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Everything is in the header. If I use a form, the problem is still here

Comment: Well then your problem is more likely the file upload itself, and not the actual sending of the mail. (That most likely rather fails because the multipart mail you _tried_ to assemble will hardly be correct, if the file content could not be properly read in the first place.) Have you researched yet how to check if a file upload went ok or had errors ...?

Comment: anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php